# Compiled in memory Assembly object to bytes[]

Tags: .net-4.0

I am generate assembly object in memory and need to get it byte representation.
I've following code but today I need that it to be done in memory

```
var assembly = GetMyAssembly();
var binary = File.ReadAllBytes(assembly.Location);
```

I've looked into Assembly builder methods and Assembly methods but can't find appropriate methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible in the runtime.

The only possible solution is to use WinDbg and SOS to dump the assembly. But then again, all my attempts at doing that exact same thing has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about saving straight to a `byte[]`, but you can save a dynamic assembly (defined using `AssemblyBuilder`), using [`AssemblyBuilder.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zwdfdeh.aspx), and then load it using `File.ReadAllBytes`. You can create it in a temporary directory, and delete it when you're done.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So, my point is doing it in memory. Saving on disk I already did.